# nodeclipse dont work on Titanium or Aptana

Tags: node.js, titanium, aptana, nodeclipse

I try to install nodeclipse on Titanium Studio, I added the link `http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/`, I got all the packages, but when I install them, Titanium warns me that lot of them already exist, and I let him install the other ones.

But after the installation ends, and restarting Titanium, i dont find the Node.js support.

That happened too on Aptana Studio.

here is the video showing that:

http://youtu.be/Lho06QBjRWY

Google drive pictures:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-Iu7VFIRkh4VnNic0g5OHNIZzQ&usp=sharing

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share screenshot or list of installed plugins, e.g. Help -> About -> Installation Details... button. Also screenshots during installing would help too.

Comment: @PaulVerest i recorded a video for that.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access it here, in China

Comment: @PaulVerest i added google drive link (screen shots)

Comment: @PaulVerest i uploaded them directly here (to imghur) , i dident know that google drive is blocked too!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install ALL plugins. E.g. latest Mylyn and EGit may be not compatible with Aptana that run on Eclipse 3.x API.

If you don't know what to install, there is picture on http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/

> Below is Enide-Recommended-Set-for-Nodejs for example.

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Nodeclipse-Updates-Enide-Recommended-Set-for-Nodejs.png))</sub>

Also look at Enide Studio 2014 http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/

Here is  Enide Studio 2014.17 for win32 with ADT (Android tools) installed,
that I use

[image: EnideStudio-2014-17-plus-ADT.png]

If there are still questions, raise issue on https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/

Comment: is that because there are packages that conflicts?
i did the inverse way, i downloaded the `Enide-Studio-2014.17-luna-SR1-win64-20141011.zip` and installed the monjadb, pydev, and other plugin except the titanium, and it worked, so i guess it is titanium bug?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for discussion and guessing

Comment: Titanium is still based on Eclipse 3.x platform while Eclipse Luna is 4.4 version. There are likely some incompatibilities.

Comment: that is the issue, i will upload pictures from the fresh install as soon as i get home